# Any way to get all visible windows' file names in Rust?

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm looking for a function or a library that would provide the function(s) with which I could get all visible windows' file names. By file names I mean the files that were used to start the process that is showing the window.

I'v heard of the winapi Rust library and got this code (from ChatGPT lmao):

```
unsafe fn get_file_name_from_process_id(pid: u32) -> Option<String> {
  // Open the process with PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ permissions
  let process_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, pid);
  if process_handle.is_null() {
      return None;
  }

  // Get Length of the process image name
  let mut size: u32 = 0;
  QueryFullProcessImageNameW(process_handle, 0, ptr::null_mut(), &mut size);

  // Allocate a buffer for the process image name
  let mut buffer: Vec<u16> = Vec::with_capacity(size as usize);

  // Get the process image name
  if QueryFullProcessImageNameW(process_handle, 0, buffer.as_mut_ptr(), &mut size) != 0 {
    // Convert the buffer to a Rust String
    let process_path = OsString::from_wide(&buffer).to_string_lossy().into_owned();

    // Get the file name from the process path
    if let Some(file_name) = Path::new(&process_path).file_name().and_then(|s| s.to_str()) {
      CloseHandle(process_handle);

      Some(file_name.to_string())
    } else {
      // Close the handle in case of failure
      CloseHandle(process_handle);

      None
    }
  } else {
    // Close the handle in case of failure
    CloseHandle(process_handle);

    None
  }
}
```

And then I use this to get the file name:

```
  let file_name: String = get_file_name_from_process_id(GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, ptr::null_mut())).unwrap_or("default".to_string());
```

but I always get "default" (it's failing).

Comment: Add some debug prints between each operation to figure out where it's failing. For instance, perhaps `GetWindowsThreadProcessId` is failing before even getting to the function. Or maybe `OpenProcess` is failing.

Comment: That's a rather odd problem to want to solve. It is usually the precursor to an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Other than that, it pretty much boils down to enumerating all "visible" windows (which is rather complicated), calling `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` for each window, opening the process and asking for the process image.